# Render custom fields of Taxonomy page D7

Tags: drupal-7, taxonomy

Assume I have a Vocabulary named "Job Titles". This vocabulary contains several custom fields.

```
"JOB TITLES" (Vocabulary)
 |
 |-- name (Default Field)
 |-- description (Default Field)
 |-- reference_url (Custom Field)
 |-- help_link (Custom Field)
```

Above vocabulary contains 2 custom fields that I can see when adding or editing a taxonomy term.

My question is, how can I use them on my page.tpl? How can I access them on template.php with hook_page_preprocess() ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunally, I haven't found a good solution yet. I solved **temporarily** so:

**Custom field:**

```
$output = (isset($term->field_FIELDNAME['und'][0]['safe_value']))? $term->field_FIELDNAME['und'][0]['safe_value'] : '' ;
```

**Term's Description:**

```
$output = filter_xss_admin($term->description);
```

**Where $term is:**

```
$tid = (int)arg(2);
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
```

I repeat, the **custom field solution above is not the best practice, and it's also unpredictable**, so use it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

To display text at the bottom of the term page, I added 2 new fields to a taxonomy vocabulary ('field_term_heading' and 'field_term_footer'). I found that it created a rather ungainly nested array. This is what I added to page.tpl.php to display it.

```
<?php if ( arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' && is_numeric(arg(2)) ): ?>

    <?php $page_term = taxonomy_term_load(arg(2));
        if ($page_term->field_footer_heading) {
        print '<h2 class="block-title">'.($page_term->field_footer_heading['und'][0]['safe_value']).'</h2>';
        }
    ?>
    <?php $page_term = taxonomy_term_load(arg(2));
        if ($page_term->field_footer_text) {
        print '<div class="content">'.($page_term->field_footer_text['und'][0]['safe_value']).'</div>';
        }
    ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```